# What's the point of a release burndown chart?

Tags: scrum, agile

I don't seem to find them accurate at all for forecasting. They are probably worse than Gantt in some ways, since Gantt gives someone a high level idea of what we aim to achieve and by when.

Every time I have used them, they give a high level forecast which is not a reflection of what actually happens, given that velocity fluctuates. Since velocity fluctuates, what is the point of using them?

Answer (score 3):

The best use I can see for release burndown charts are on projects with calendar based deadlines.

Some examples might be:

- Product development for an Olympic Games
- A charity running a Christmas campaign
- A betting company releasing products leading up to a big race event

With this kind of situation a release burndown can help to show *what will not be ready in time*.

The release burndown would be continually updated with the latest velocity and any backlog changes. You could imagine then the business users realising that some backlog items are not going to make it and so altering their plans to adjust to this.

Comment: Ah right, so if the burn down chart is behind schedule, a use case would be showing it to the dev team and telling them that we need to up the velocity?

Comment: I'm not sure that is a good use case. Tell a team to up the velocity and most likely they will just cut quality and spend less time on design. A better use case would be that the business adjusts to the realities of the speed with which things are getting delivered.

Comment: I have sometimes found that when I've done it this way, the team works harder without quality being affected - since the release burn up has identified complacency.

Answer (score 1):

When your velocity is too unstable, you can't make any solid predictions. Even with a solid velocity a lot depends on the level of detail on your backlog, the quality of the estimates and the level of refinement.

Forecasting at the Product Backlog Item Level for more than a few sprints is wrought with issues. If it isn't the quality of the estimates and the level of refinement, it's that priorities will still change, you should expect feedback on the upcoming sprints and the understanding of the product/problem may change significantly.

The Release Burndown is nice when you're still thinking in releases and a lot of the practices are still in place. Instead, you may want to look at ways of estimating at a higher level than the Product Backlog Items, use Features or Epics and establish their own relative estimates.

Answer (score 1):

All forecasting, no matter the tool, are marginal at best in terms of accuracy.  If you are forecasting definitively, a straight line of performance or a single value, then your forecasting will always suffer from severe low accuracy.

All work, all activity, are probabilistic.  You need to forecast in a probabilistic way, a way that enables you to derive a range of future results with some known probability across that range.  This holds true whether you're doing a burn down chart, an S curve analysis, earned value, or any type of predictive analytics.  You are looking for a high degree of precision in your estimation while accuracy remains marginal at best.  So understand the difference between precision and accuracy or reliability and validity.

Now, when dealing with stakeholders, you cannot report a range of results.  They expect a definitive value.  But this does not stop you from forecasting probable results and then reporting where your analysis suggests is most likely.  When you understand that range, you understand the risk above and below the definitive value you reported.  If your final result falls within the probabilistic range you identified, your forecasting capability is top notch and that is all we have at our disposal with which to work at our current level of technology and smarts.

Comment: Thanks, that is what I am finding, from Gaant, Release burn down, nothing is ever 100% accurate. I do find that standard burn down charts helps a lot, by showing it during stand ups motivates the team to work harder so they can finish their sprint.

Answer (score 0):

Burndown charts are only useful if you know exactly what you need to build up front.

Even on the scale of two weeks, it's nearly impossible to break things down so fine grained up front that each and every task is accounted for *before you start building it*. Even if your team *can* achieve this level of detailed planning up front, before the sprint begins, *should they*? Is the value they provide worth the the huge amount of effort it takes to make an accurate burndown chart?

Imagine a project where your PO *literally doesn't know* what they ultimately need. All they have is a vision. How could you estimate well enough to provide an accurate burndown?

Imagine a project where your team has never worked with the technology that they'll need to work with. How could they possibly estimate well enough to provide an accurate burndown?

I don't provide these examples of when burndown charts *just don't work* because I'm anti-burndowns or anything. They can be useful if you have a stable backlog and a lot of known knowns and very few unknown unknowns. I just wanted to illustrate that you may be totally justified in your frustration.

Burn-ups and Cumulative flow charts are often used in lieu of burndowns. They might be worth trying for your team.

Answer (score -1):

Gantt charts are good to depict the dependency and relationship between the tasks and work packages. We can get the most from PERT, when combining numbers with Gantt charts, which is also known as Critical Path Method. CPM and PERT are a foundation of predictive project management (Waterfall/Traditional).

The Burndown chart, as a simple tool, provides the Product Owner, and the Development Team, an indicator to predict the completion date. It is also a very simple baseline for measurement of the project and sprint progress.

The burndown chart is useful to increase the transparency among the DevTeam. Everybody understands what the current situation is. Also, Product Owner could use it to communicate with stakeholders and customer. To get more time or to reprioritise the Product Backlog to maximise the value of the project.

Comment: Sure, at the same time a burn down chart does not tell stakeholders what will be completed and when it will be completed by. It's estimation is based on the whole of the product backlog with story points approximately put on cards